# Idea behind this way of showing injectivity in a certain proof

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I would show injectivity of the function $h$ by showing $f(C) \cap A-C = \emptyset$. This is true, because $f(C) = f(\bigcup\limits_{n\geq 0} f^n(A-B)) = \bigcup\limits_{n\geq 1} f^n(A-B) \subset C$ and $ A-C \cap C = \emptyset$. $f$ and $id_{A-C}$ are both injective and were are done.

But what is the author's idea ? In other words, how do
$A-B \subset C$,$ f(C) \subset C$,$f^m(A-B) \cap f^n(A-B) = \emptyset, n > m \geq 0$,$f$ is one-one imply the injectivity of $h$ and why is this "better" here?

---

Source: *McCleary - A First Course in Topology: Continuity and Dimension*.

Actual proof taken from: *Cox - A proof of the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem, American Math. Monthly 75, 508*

[image]

Comment: Can you precise the whole question? Is $f$ defined from $A$ to $A$ and $C \subset A$?

Comment: you probably overlooked the line "Lemma 1.9". $B \subset A$, $f: A -> B$

Comment: Okay. You didn't even notice which Lemma from which book. Maybe I don't have the same book as yours?

Comment: thanks, edited OP

Comment: As you are on Topology, the author wants you to use a topological approach. That's why the idea is better here. Thus, consider that (1) "the union of any number of open ball is an open ball too" (2) we strictly need to have $B \subset A$ to be able to discuss injectivity for $f$. We must combine these two assumptions. Try to figure out yourself, and come back.

Comment: @freehumorist - there is no topology defined here. Schroeder-Bernstein is about cardinality, not topology. It is covered in this topology textbook because it is a very useful theorem for topology. But that does not make the theorem topological.

Comment: Your proof does indeed show that $h$ is injective. But the author also needs to show that $h$ is a "correspondence", by which I assume they mean $h$ is surjective. Likely they are also setting up for that part of the proof.